# allow web designer to change password?

Tags: password-management

I have a Linux web server, and I've created a user (in`/etc/passwd`) for a web designer.  I pre-set her password and she uses the `sftp` uploading capability of her web design software to upload content.  This works, but I don't like the fact that there is no way for her to change her password on her own.  The web design software (*Dreamweaver*) does not seem to provide this capability.   What's the easiest way for me to provide this?

Answer (score 1):

Allow ssh connection and change login shell to "/usr/bin/passwd". Then login to ssh:

```
$ ssh servername
Last login: Sun Feb 20 12:37:33 2011 from 10.0.2.2
Changing password for ooshro.
(current) UNIX password: 
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password: 
passwd: password updated successfully
Connection to localhost closed.
```

Comment: By doing that you also disable sftp.

Comment: Also, you can give parameters to passwd over ssh, which is not really big problem.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround (not bullet-proof, but working for casual usage) for disabling ssh, and allowing sftp is to put `passwd` to user profile; edit file `~/.profile` (not yours, that user only), add line

```
/usr/bin/passwd
exit 0
```

to the end of the file.

It's possible to circumvent that, but if your web developer is not really malicious, it shouldn't be a problem.

Then when web developer connects using ssh (for example [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) for Windows), there is prompt for old password and then two prompts for new passwod:

```
Linux chaos 2.6.26-2-xen-686 #1 SMP Wed Aug 19 08:47:57 UTC 2009 i686
Last login: never
Changing password for tmpuser.
(current) UNIX password: 
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password: 
passwd: password updated successfully
Connection to server1 closed.
```